# Redirect away from login page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

I'm trying to find a way to prevent the login screen from showing up when user makes a mistake filling out the login form.

So, right now, I have the login form printed on a custom template. But if the users makes a mistake filling it out, it redirects them to the wordpress form to try again. I want to redirect away from that.

This is the code I had but it's not working.

```
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_invalid_login');

function redirect_invalid_login(){
    global $error;

    if($error)
        header('Location: '.get_bloginfo('url').'/client-login/?message=6');
}
```

Now login_form is too late I believe because stuff already gets printed to the page. I haven't been able to find a hook that works. Is there a hook for this? Or perhaps a different way to do it?

Comment: `it redirects them to the wordpress form to try again` isn't that behavior by design? Why do you want to change it?

Comment: I am building a site where the user should have no access to wordpress backend, or see any backend at all. So I've made it so the wordpress login form is on a template page

Comment: If they make a mistake I want them to stay on that form and not be redirected

Comment: Thanks for feeding back. I'm afraid I don't follow. If the user "makes a mistake" when filling out the form, it means they have access to it in the first place. What do you mean by "user"? A site visitor or a fellow contributor? If site vistor, you can set WP to not accept logins, or you can use .htaccess to block the login page. But you cannot block contributors from the login page, else how will they contribute?

Comment: I'm still using the wordpress login system, just not the default wordpress page. I put the login form on a custom template that I made. I don't want them to ever get to the wordpress login screen. I have a template with that form on it for that reason. Now when they fill out that form incorrectly, it sends them to the wordpress login, but I want it to redirect them to My custom form instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is the solution:

```
add_action('login_redirect', 'redirect_login', 10, 3);

function redirect_login($redirect_to, $url, $user) {
    if($user->errors['empty_password']){
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/client-login/?message=6');
    }
    else if($user->errors['empty_username']){
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/client-login/?message=7');
    }
    else if($user->errors['invalid_username']){
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/client-login/?message=8');
    }
    else if($user->errors['incorrect_password']){
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/client-login/?message=9');
    }
    else{
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/client-login');
    }

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'redirect_invalid_login' );
function redirect_invalid_login() {
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/client-login/?message=6');
        exit;
}
```

Comment: That got me half way there. It only works if both fields are filled out. But if you only fill out the password or username field, then it still kicks you to wordpress' page. I did some research and wp_authenticate is a pluggable function so I am going to give that a try and see what comes of it.

Comment: Sure and please let me know what you get. Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you know if there is a hook that will check for a single field?

Comment: Sorry i really don't know. :-(